# how to subtraction, multiplication and division with looping statement

Tags: android

i am create android application for subtraction, multiplication, division and addition with looping statement

```
case 1: if user insert= 3 then looping = 3x
case 2: user input 1st looping = 5 then dialog show = 5
case 3: user input 2nd = 10 then dialog show 5+10
case 4: user input 3rd = 90 then dialog show 5+10+90
```

this is my code for addition

```
package com.test.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class arithmatic extends Activity {

     int y = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoginputloop, null);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(arithmatic.this)
       // .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("Operator")
        .setView(v)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

              EditText op = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.operator);
              int n = Integer.valueOf(op.getText().toString());

            for (int i = 0;i<n;i++){

                LayoutInflater inflater = arithmatic.this.getLayoutInflater();
                final View v2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoginputnumber, null) ;
                new AlertDialog.Builder(arithmatic.this)
                    //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("input number")
                    .setView(v2)
                    .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

                            EditText number = (EditText)v2.findViewById(R.id.number);
                            String a = number.getText().toString();
                            int x = Integer.valueOf(a);
                            y = y + x; //my formula to addition looping

                            new AlertDialog.Builder(arithmatic.this)
                                .setTitle("result")
                                .setMessage(Integer.toString(y))
                                .setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                                    }
                                })
                                .show(); 

                        }
                  })
                  .show();

              }

             }

          })

          .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                 finish();
               }
           })
           .show();
    }
}
```

how to create formula to subtraction, multiplication and division?

Comment: Are those cases or numeric steps?

Comment: This may be the most blatant homework posting of all time.

Comment: Take a look at this line.  I don't think it will do what you think it does: "int y = y + x;"

Comment: numeric steps thegrinner,,,,
what is formula to subtraction, multiplication and division with looping statement?

Comment: y = 0; y = 0 + x; if x = 5,then 5 + 0 then y = 5, if x again = 8 then y = 5+8 for display to setmessage into dialog

Answer (score 0):

The formula for subtraction is y-x 
The formula for multiplication is y*x
the formula for division is y/x

If you make a seperate method for each it will be clearer.

Also if youre trying to continually wait for another number then what you wrote is not going to work. You can have an array of numbers that the user entered and do the calculations at the end.

Comment: do you have an alert dialog inside of an alert dialog?